# problem in booting Ubuntu along side another SSD got ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, root

Hey guys i have the following problem:

I have a USB 3 USB flash 240GB.
When i try to boot it alongside Kingston SSD 240GB i get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvprB.jpg

But when i boot the Kingston ssd it works fine.

> ATA KINGSTON SH103S3 = /dev/sda #Ubuntu 13.10

The USB 3 flash

> Mushkin Ventura Ultra = /dev/sdb #Ubuntu 14.04

---

> fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00014928

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   468860927   234179585    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   468860927   234179584   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 214.4 GB, 214354100224 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26060 cylinders, total 418660352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 25.4 GB, 25442648064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3093 cylinders, total 49692672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdb: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000dc461

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   468860927   234179585    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   468860927   234179584   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000672c1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  1953521663   976759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc4      1559100768  1561017695      958464    0  Empty
```